# VB to Insert in Access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm trying to insert data into a MSaccess db using VB but having some trouble finishing the code

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1

Dim provider As String
Dim dataFile As String
Dim connString As String
Public myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
Public dr As OleDbDataReader

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'BD Connection
    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
    dataFile = "C:\Users\Peter\Documents\Database1.accdb"
    connString = provider & dataFile
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
End Sub

Private Sub FindButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FindButton.Click
    'Query BD
    myConnection.Open()
    DescriptionText.Clear()
    CostText.Clear()
    PriceText.Clear()
    Dim str As String
    str = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE (Code = '" & CodeText.Text & "')"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While dr.Read()
        DescriptionText.Text = dr("Description").ToString
        CostText.Text = dr("Cost").ToString
        PriceText.Text = dr("Price").ToString
    End While
    myConnection.Close()
End Sub
Private Sub AddButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AddButton.Click
    'Insert BD
    Dim str As String

    myConnection.Open()
    CodeText.Clear()
    DescriptionText.Clear()
    CostText.Clear()
    PriceText.Clear()

    str = "INSERT INTO Table1 (Code, Description, Cost, Price) Values (CodeText.Text, DescriptionText.Text, CostText.Text, PriceText.Text) VALUES ('CodeText.Text', 'DescriptionText.Text', 'CostText.Text', 'PriceText.Text')"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    MsgBox("saved")

    myConnection.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

My query sub work fine but when I try to insert data it gives me an error on the "cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()".

Can you help me find whats wrong?

Comment: Have another look on that query you're executing...

Answer (score 3):

Your `INSERT` query syntax is not correct. You cannot simply add the `Textbox.Text` as strings into the values. You have to escape them.

But I would highly recommend using parametrized queries for both `SELECT` and `INSERT` statements:

```
Dim insert As String = "INSERT INTO Table1 (Code, Description, Cost, Price) Values (?, ?, ?, ?)"
Dim insertCmd As New OleDbCommand(insert, myConnection)
insertCmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Code", CodeText.Text))
insertCmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Description", DescriptionText.Text))
insertCmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Cost", Double.Parse(CostText.Text)))
insertCmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Price", Double.Parse(PriceText.Text)))
insertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

I assume that your `Cost` and `Price` database fields are numeric so I used `Double.Parse` to convert them. `Code`seems to be a text field so no convert needed. If my suggested types are not correct you have to adjust this, there is `Integer.Parse`, `Decimal.Parse` etc.

Finally here the `SELECT` part optimized:

```
 Dim qry As String = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE (Code = ?)"
 Dim selectCmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(qry, myConnection)
 selectCmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Code", CodeText.Text))
 selectCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

[More about parametrized queries](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/26/parameter-queries-in-asp-net-with-ms-access)

Comment: Thanks Alex. This code gives me the error "BC30451 'Description' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level". This error is with "Description", "Cost" and "Price" but not with "code".

Comment: I had a typo in the textbox names which I have corrected in my answer. But honestly, you know your code better than me... with a little bit of research you could have fixed it by yourself ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
str = "INSERT INTO Table1 (Code, Description, Cost, Price) Values ('" + CodeText.Text + "', '" + DescriptionText.Text + "', '" + CostText.Text + "', '" + PriceText.Text + "')"
```

Comment: Thans Karthick. Good point but when I click add (insert) it add a row (with ID) in the DB but with no data.