# How to add New row in datagridview connected with ms access vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

how can i add new items from textbox to datagridview then to ms access database ?
my code is :

```
Try
            Dim d As New DBConnect
            Dim indx As Integer
            indx = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            d.Editdata(String.Format("INSERT INTO Client (ClientName, ClientAddress, ClientPhone, ClientCredit, ClientLastPay) values('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}')", FlatTextBox1.Text, FlatTextBox2.Text, FlatTextBox3.Text, FlatTextBox4.Text, FlatTextBox5.Text))
            loadcreadit()
            DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1).Selected = True
            DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            otherdata()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

i have error look at this pic : **https://s31.postimg.org/ew7cxpfy3/Sans_titre.png**
hope to help me !

Comment: Use bound parameters to avoid datatype mismatchs. I bet `ClientCredit` and `ClientLastPay` are *not* strings.You can find how to use them in an older [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36304962/2882256) of me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB to Insert in Access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36304367/vb-to-insert-in-access)